# Integration test with DBUnit FileNotFoundException Java

Tags: java, spring

The integration test which i am writing now has strange exception. I will copy the stack trace and the test for more information. I do not understand why it is trying to search ***LoginControllerTest-context.xml***. I have never use file with that name.

**LoginControllerTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@Transactional
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionDbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@DatabaseSetup(type = DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT, value = "login.xml")
public class LoginControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.xmlConfigSetup("applicationContext.xml").build();
    }

    @Test
    @ExpectedDatabase("login.xml")
    public void testShowForm() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/login")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view().name("/login"))
                .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WebContent/j/login.jsp"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("id", nullValue())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("email", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("username", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("hostname", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("pass", isEmptyOrNullString())));
    }
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [com/profiles/controller/test/LoginControllerTest-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/profiles/controller/test/LoginControllerTest-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:93)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.buildApplicationContext(TestContext.java:198)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:126)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:85)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:95)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:139)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/profiles/controller/test/LoginControllerTest-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: Because that is the default behavior if you add an empty `@ContextConfiguration`. It looks for internal `@Configuration` classes and for the file `<testclass-name>-context.xml`.

Comment: @M. Deinum Thank you.

Comment: @M. Deinum Can i still use **LoginControllerTest-context.xml** as applicationContext.xml ?

Comment: Why? You are trying to use a Spring Unit test for something that isn't a Spring Unit/Integration test and only for setting up data. I would let the test framework load the `applicationcontext.xml` (specify it as location). Add `@WebAppConfiguraton` to your test class, create a field of type `WebApplicationContext` with `@Autowired` and use `MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup` instead.